# How to implement a classifier without features in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, mode

How can I build a trivial classifier in R that checks the number of each possible output value, doesn't use features and assigns the most frequent value to the test data? Each test data instance is associated with the most frequent target value.

In R I do as follows:

```
trivial.classifier <- lm(target_value ~ -., data=train.set)
```

Is this what I am looking for?

Comment: The idea of a no-information learner is of interest to StatsSE, but if the question is only about implementation, then perhaps you'd better ask this to be moved to StackOverflow.

Comment: what is target_value? Is it a binary or a multiple categorical variable? Furthermore, if you are asking about implementation, as @Firebug pointed out, this is not the right place for it.

Comment: From a terminology perspective, this is often called the ZeroR classifier.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to classify to the mode of your training data?

Then, this could be a useful snippet

```
classify.to.the.mode <- function(traindata){
     unique.data <- unique(traindata)
     prediction <- unique.data[which.max(tabulate(match(traindata,unique.data)))]
     return(prediction)
}

x <- c(1,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,5)

classify.to.the.mode(x)
```